# Qt Symbian audio level

Tags: qt, audio, symbian, qml, volume

How can I get the current system audio level of a Symbian device because i want applications volume level to be the same as say for example the native music player's.

Any ideas?

PS. I'm using Qt Game Enabler for sound.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Qt for Symbian provides any API to control the volume level.
You will have to dive into the world of Symbian C++.

You should look at this:

[Programmatically change phone ( symbian ) speaker volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891504/programmatically-change-phone-symbian-speaker-volume)